# Why am I getting error at loading image from JSON to tableview using kingfisher?

Tags: ios, json, swift, imageview, tableview

I'm trying to load an image obtained from JSON response into `tableView` with the help of `Kingfisher` library.
this is the image obtained from JSON response:

```
"image": "/static/restaurants/image-1593600873191.jpg"
```

Now I'm writing this code in `cellForRow` method :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.lblName.text = arrUsers[0].data?.categories[0].name
        let url = URL(string:arrUsers[0].data?.bestOffers[0].image ?? "No Url")
       cell.imgName.kf.setImage(with: url)
        return cell
      }
```

In the above code, I'm converting the JSON response of the image into a URL and then passing it into `setImage` method.

The label is being set into `tableView` but the image isn't being loaded into `tableViewCell` and I'm getting this error in the console.
[please find attached the screenshot for refernce.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3bVx.png)

Comment: /static/restaurants/ -is a directory created in your app or assets directory?

Comment: @Satheesh it is assets directory as i have just received this value as json response.

Comment: " assets directory" in your app, or with a remote url? You need to put the base url before.

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65114085/14437411

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
let url = URL(string:arrUsers[0].data?.bestOffers[0].image ?? "No Url")
```

To

```
let url = URL(string: "https://yourwebsiteaddress" + (arrUsers[0].data?.bestOffers[0].image ?? "No Url"))
```