# Can't display image from url using Kingfisher

Tags: ios, swift, url, kingfisher

I imported Kingfisher

```
 import UIKit
 import Kingfisher
```

This is my simple code to can explain the problem
Creating an imageView and trying display image from URL

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var image:UIImageView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let rawstring = "https://apis.baytelhekma.com/zinzo/public/storage/" + #"products\November2020\eUWwRjNCYCdHUjGIQiJk.png"#
        
        let url = URL(string: rawstring)
        image.kf.setImage(with: url)

       
    }


}
```

Comment: Do not use only `setImage(with:)` use the method with the completion handler that might return an error which might give more info about why it failed: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/blob/2a6d1135af3915547c4b08c3b154a05e6f1075a3/Sources/Extensions/ImageView%2BKingfisher.swift#L82

Comment: failure(Kingfisher.KingfisherError.imageSettingError(reason: Kingfisher.KingfisherError.ImageSettingErrorReason.emptySource))
This is the output also URL isn't empty you can check it 
https://apis.baytelhekma.com/zinzo/public/storage/products\November2020\eUWwRjNCYCdHUjGIQiJk.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your url again as I've tried another url and it works fine, you can check it:

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var image:UIImageView!
    let rawstring = "https://i.insider.com/5e820b04671de06758588fb8?width=700&format=jpeg&auto=webp"

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            
            let url = URL(string: rawstring)
            image.kf.setImage(with: url)

           
        }

}
```

or you can make url like this if it helped:

```
 let rawstring = "https://apis.baytelhekma.com/zinzo/public/storage/products/November2020/eUWwRjNCYCdHUjGIQiJk.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is incorrect url, your're using `\` in address.

So

```
let rawstring = "https://apis.baytelhekma.com/zinzo/public/storage/" + #"products\November2020\eUWwRjNCYCdHUjGIQiJk.png"
```

provides

```
https://apis.baytelhekma.com/zinzo/public/storage/products\November2020\eUWwRjNCYCdHUjGIQiJk.png
```

which is **incorrect url**

---

Changing it to

```
let rawstring = "https://apis.baytelhekma.com/zinzo/public/storage/" + #"products/November2020/eUWwRjNCYCdHUjGIQiJk.png"#
```

or simply to

```
let rawString = "https://apis.baytelhekma.com/zinzo/public/storage/products/November2020/eUWwRjNCYCdHUjGIQiJk.png"
```

will fix your issue